# Infinite Loop in For Loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I was trying to change my program to show the names of the months instead.

```
        private static void getValues(double [] array)
        {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

            //get the values of the months
            for (int i = 0 ; i  < array.length ; i ++)
            {
                    System.out.println("Enter the value for the month "  + (i+1));
                    array[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    if (array[i] < 0 )
                    {
                        System.out.println("The value SHOULD NOT BE a NEGATIVE number");
                        break;
                    }

            }
    }
}
```

I changed the code to the following:

```
String  [] month = {"January", "February","March",etc};

for ( int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i ++)
{
  for (int index = 0; month.length; index++)
   {
     System.out.println("The rainfall value of the " + month[index]);
       array[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
                if (array[i] < 0 )
                {
                    System.out.println("The value SHOULD NOT BE a NEGATIVE number");
                    break;
                }
    }
 }
```

It ran, but I created an infinite loop. 
Where did I miss it?
Thank you so much, guys.

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: `for (int index = 0; month.length; index++)` did you mean `index < month.length;`?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant,  I typed it wrong.

Comment: Like I said I turned in my assignment already. I just want to learn more to improve my code, more user-Friendly. Thank you @Turing85 :d.

Comment: Hey Du Pham welcome to Stack Overflow. To make your question more clear, delete all the explanation and code except for the part with the loop and the month array. Just tell us you experience an infinite loop there, that's enough.

Comment: How did you manage to compile your program if you had an int where it expected a boolean?

Comment: Thank you @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere. I just want you guys to know that I actually code the program. I know it just a small program for you guys, but hey I am learning. And thank you for making my post clearer.

Comment: I'm wondering why you didn't post the exact code that created the infinite loop.

Comment: that was the exact code.

Comment: @DuPham what IDE and compiler do you use? The second bit of code will not compile using Oracle's Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a check in your second for loop.

```
for (int index = 0; month.length; index++)
```

The condition should be `index < month.length` not `month.length`.

Comment: This would be an infinite loop in C, but in Java it should say `error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean`

Comment: Yes, I was confused myself. OP stated they posted exact code, so I'm curious as to what compiler they use.